# div element and CheckedMultiSelect

Tags: dojo

Hi Kindly help me Get the output...I am trying to display the selected items from the CheckedMultiSelect inside a div element..Please help me out in finding the error

```
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">
<style type="text/css">
@import "dojox/form/resources/CheckedMultiSelect.css";
    </style>
<script>dojoConfig = {parseOnLoad: true}</script>
<script src="dojo/dojo.js"></script>
<script>
require(["dojox/form/CheckedMultiSelect"]);
 require(["dijit/registry"], function(registry){
   var a=registry.byId("multiselect"); 
   dom.byId("textNode2").innerHTML="Found my text box.  It has value: [" + a.get('value') + "] and its primary DOM node tag name is: [" + dNode.tagName + "]";
        });
</script>
<body class="claro">
<select multiple="true" data-dojo-type="dojox.form.CheckedMultiSelect" id="multiselect" name="multiselect" >
      <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
      <option value="VA" selected="selected">Virginia</option>
      <option value="WA">Washington</option>
      <option value="FL">Florida</option>
      <option value="CA">California</option>
 </select>
 <div id="textNode2" style="background-color: lightgray"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting? What version of dojo are you using?

Comment: Am using 1.9...i don receive any error messages...

Comment: Everything is fine,,,but i dont get the selected items in the list to be  displayed in the div element

Comment: The previous question that you asked that was very similar to this was already answered. Use `.get('value')` and `dojo/on`.

Comment: Thank you..it Worked for a single item..not for multiple items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in the code you supplied is that in the statement that reads:

```
dom.byId("textNode2").innerHTML="Found my text box.  It has value: [" + a.get('value') + "] and its primary DOM node tag name is: [" + dNode.tagName + "]";
    });
```

You are making reference to a variable called `dom` which is not defined.  In addition, you are referring to a variable called `dNode` which is not declared.

Since the script is running in the head section, it is also possible that the DOM is simply not ready at the time that the script is executed.

I coded up the following and it worked:

```
<script>
require(["dijit/registry", "dojo/dom", "dojo/parser", "dojox/form/CheckedMultiSelect", "dojo/domReady!"], function(registry, dom, parser){
parser.parse();
var a=registry.byId("multiselect"); 
dom.byId("textNode2").innerHTML="Found my text box.  It has value: [" + a.get('value') + "]";
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you..It worked..If suppose i select multiple checkboxes at runtime .How can i make all the selected items appear in the textbox

Comment: All the selected items should appear in the textbox separated by a delimiter like comma(,)

Comment: Thank You all for helping out .....
Can you help me in creating the code in a programmatic way.

Comment: I responded to your post earlier.  I saw that you flagged it answered and I grew my reputation.  I then saw that you removed the "flagged as answered" and reduced my reputation again.  Now, even though I perceive the original question as answered, you are flagging the question as un-answered and now asking for help in programming further beyond the original question which was asked and answered.

Comment: i apologize for that.i thought if flagged as answered..i wont receive further reponse thats y....Am new in Site..Kindly understand

Comment: No problems my friend.  I too am very new here myself.  I will look for your questions and if I can assist, I will be glad to.  I don't think StackOverflow will allow questions such as "Please code this up for me" ... but if you have an attempt by yourself and run into describable problems that are generic in nature, you will usually find assistance. I follow the Dojo tag so will be looking out to assist.